How to test if the slope = 1 and intercept = 0 for linear model, based on major axis (MA) regression?
I understand the output of simple linear models gives results about testing if slope and intercept equal to 0:
> library(lmodel2)
> df <- data.frame(
+   v1 = rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2),
+   v2 = rnorm(100, mean = 20, sd = 3)
+ )
> 
> 
> fit = lm(v2~v1, data = df)
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = v2 ~ v1, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.5651 -2.0809  0.3728  2.5557  5.7576 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 19.18410    1.61715  11.863   <2e-16 ***
v1           0.07093    0.15653   0.453    0.651    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.079 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.002091,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.008092 
F-statistic: 0.2053 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.6515

Then it is possible to test if the slope = 1, by using the codes below
library(car)
linearHypothesis(fit, "v1 = 1")

Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
v1 = 1

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: v2 ~ v1

  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1     99 1499.4                                  
2     98 1089.5  1    409.88 36.868 2.402e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

The output suggests slope is significantly different from 1.
My first question is whether my understanding above is correct or not?
Afterwards, I would to use major axis (MA) regression instead of OLS. Thus, I used R package lmodel2 as follows:
> fit <- lmodel2(v2 ~ v1 , df, range.y = "interval", range.x = "interval", 99)
> reg <- fit$regression.results[2,]
> print(reg)
  Method Intercept  Slope Angle (degrees) P-perm (1-tailed)
2     MA -181.6842 19.876        87.11977              0.32
> conf = fit$confidence.intervals[2,]
> print(conf)
  Method 2.5%-Intercept 97.5%-Intercept 2.5%-Slope 97.5%-Slope
2     MA        78.5217        -16.4791   3.587222   -5.779601

My second question is: How to test if the slope = 1 and intercept = 0 for MA regression?

In formula notation, the model you described is fit using v2 ~ 0 + offset(v1). I have no idea how to use lmodel2 packages and to test parsimonious models. If you are just using least squares, you could call aov(fit, fitnull) where fitnull <- lm(v2 ~ 0 + offset(v1), data=df).

You have the confidence intervals for both of them already, why do you need to do the test?
